# add 12 months for Now Date

Tags: javascript, typescript

> Hi, I would like to add 12 months and subtract 1 day for my current
>   date.

**Example :**

1. **valStartDate :2018-01-20**
2. **expected_date:2019-01-19**

**I try below code but error** "getFullYear() not a function to allow"

```
this.endDate =this.valStartDate.getFullYear()+1+'-'+this.valStartDate.getMonth()+'-'+(this.valStartDate.getDate()-1);
```

Comment: What is error message??

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular, even if it's the framwork you're using. I think you should tag typescript though

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your given start date is a date and not a string.

```
var startDate = new Date(2018, 0, 20);
var startDatePlus12Months = new Date(startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() + 12));
var expectedDate = new Date(startDatePlus12Months.getFullYear(), startDatePlus12Months.getMonth(), startDatePlus12Months.getDate() - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method of abstracting the date you want, apply this the variable and you should be good to go.

```js
var date = new Date(); // now 
var newDate = new Date(date.getFullYear() + 1, date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - 1);

console.log(newDate.toLocaleDateString());
```

`this.valStartDate.getFullYear()` In order for this to work, `this.valStartDate` must be a valid javascript date and look the same format as `new Date();` would give you.

```
Fri Apr 26 2019 11:52:15 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.endDate = new Date(this.endDate); // <= maybe you get a string date...
this.endDate.setMonth(this.endDate.getMonth() + 12);
this.endDate.setDate(this.endDate.getDate() - 1);
```

If you're getting your date from a server or from a previous Json format, maybe you need to convert it from `string` to `Date` first: `this.endDate = new Date(this.endDate);`. It seems this is your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with the help of [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
const startDate = moment('2018-01-20');
const endDate = startDate.add(12, 'months').subtract(1, 'days').toDate();
```